# Module method in Rails 6 YAML fixtures

Tags: ruby-on-rails

One model in a Rails application I'm working on has a JSON field. This can be created in the fixtures with:

```
first_record:
  name: "First Record"
  metadata:  <%= File.read("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/metadata/default.json") %>
```

...and so on. But, for some tests a value other than the default is needed in the metadata; this could be done by having separate metadata files for each record, or embedding JSON in the YAML file, but there are many records and there is much metadata. So, another option is to create a module in `lib/modules` with something like this:

```
module TestMetadataHelper

  def create_metadata(args)
    metadata = JSON.parse(File.read("#{Rails.root}/test/fixtures/files/metadata/default.json"))
    args.each do |key, value|
      metadata[key] = value
    end
    metadata.to_json
  end

end
```

And, to make this accessible in tests, this goes into test_helper.rb:

```
ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.context_class.send :include, TestMetadataHelper
```

The, in the fixtures:

```
metadata:  <%= create_metadata(field_to_change: "custom value") %>
```

Tests run perfectly well using this method, but there's one problem:

```
$ RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake db:fixtures:load                                                               
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `create_metadata' for #<#<Class:0x00007feeba246958>:0x00007feeba246890>
```

So, how about fixing this by loading my module in `config/environments/test.rb`?

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Initialization autoloaded the constant TestMetadataHelper.

Being able to do this is deprecated. Autoloading during initialization is going
to be an error condition in future versions of Rails.

Reloading does not reboot the application, and therefore code executed during
initialization does not run again. So, if you reload TestMetadataHelper, for example,
the expected changes won't be reflected in that stale Module object.

This autoloaded constant has been unloaded.

Please, check the "Autoloading and Reloading Constants" guide for solutions.
```

Having looked at that guide it's not entirely clear to me how best to handle this situation, so if anyone has any thoughts (e.g. how to fix this warning, or a better way to deal with the test requirements), please do comment.

Comment: I note that setting `config.cache_classes = true` in `config/environments/test.db` prevents the error, though whether that's good practice I cannot say.